# Multiple Git Merges

Tags: git, merge, bitbucket

We have following situation for a Bitbucket repository

1. Certain project had three branches, qa, master, and dev-project-specific.
2. One of the Devs merged qa into dev-project-specific.
3. Someone (we're not sure who) merged dev-project-specific into master
4. Someone else again merged dev-project-specific into master using Bitbucket UI, and reverted the change from terminal.

4 was done by checking out master, doing "git reset --hard {HEAD - 1}", and doing "git push --force". After 4, commit corresponding to merge from UI was removed from both data and history of master.

After all this, we're still seeing code from dev-project-specific in master. There's nothing in commit logs that indicates who did the merge (or checkin) or when.

Needless to say, we don't want anything from dev-project-specific in qa or master.

Given that this is a merge, the commits from qa and dev-project-specific are interlaced in master, and there's no way we can just reset to a commit in master and live happily ever after.

Is there a way we can reset master to a state where it does not have any changes from dev-project-specific?

Comment: Can you attach the output of `git log --pretty=format:"%h %s" --graph` to your question, so we know what the state of the repository is? You can change the commit messages if they contain private data.

Comment: Hi Ferrybig, 

Solved this in the meantime.

We were assuming merge happened at Head or Head -1, but the commit that merged was at Head - 2, and had a misleading message (it said "merging qa to dev-project-specific" instead of "merging dev-project-specific to master").

After some trial and error, we reset master to HEAD - 3, and are all set to live happily ever after. 

Thanks for taking time.